# How does UITableView dequeueReusableCell work?

Tags: uitableview

Well...I still do not really quite understand the concept and how the UITableView or UITableViewCell works. I really need a clear understanding of it to master it.

Here are a few questions that have been really bugging me for a while.

1) When the app created with a UITableView launches, all the CELLS filled with information are already displayed on the screen. **Are these cells have already been dequeued?** Is it when the dequeueReusableCell called? In other words, are these cells called dequeueReusableCells?

2) If not, how does the UITableView work? Does it create new cells when the app first launches? If the screen of the phone could, let say, display 3 cells due to screen size, does it mean that the UItableView has already created 3 cells to be displayed on the screen?

3) If the first question is not right, how and when does dequeueReusableCell method get called? Is it when the cell being recycled and appears from the bottom of the screen?

I have watched a video and the instructor said the cells that are already displayed on the phone screen are the dequeueReusableCells. And I really wanna know how and when the dequeueReusableCell method get called?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> how does the UITableView work? Does it create new cells when the app first launches?

Yes! Here’s the idea. Let’s say your table view has 2000 rows. But only 12 cells are visible at once on screen. Okay, so only 12 cells (or maybe 13 or 14) ever need to be created over the whole lifetime of the app!

> And I really wanna know how and when the dequeueReusableCell method get called

You call it, at the start of `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. That method in turn is called by the runtime whenever a cell is needed, and you get either a new cell (the initial 12 or 13 or 14 in my above example) or a reused cell (all rows to be displayed after that), and you return that for display, and so all is right with the world.

Comment: So just wonder which method gets called to create the cells at the initial launch? Also when does the tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) get called? When we scroll up and down?

Comment: Side Note - I have read your Books Matt. Well written, and is pretty amazing but it would be great if you could include a bit more details in the explanation of the code.

Comment: "So just wonder which method gets called to create the cells at the initial launch?" I told you: `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` is called and you call `dequeue`. "Also when does the tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) get called? When we scroll up and down?" It is called whenever a cell is needed. You should not worry about when this is. Just be prepared to call `dequeue` and supply a cell for the given row regardless of when the call happens.